# update php in wordpress in wampserver

Tags: php, wordpress, local, wampserver

I encountered a problem with my Wampserver. I moved my live site "WordPress website" to local server "Wampserver" it has an old version of PHP "5.6" after I moved it locally, I updated the PHP in Wampserver to PHP 7.4 it has been updated everywhere in Wampserver and CLI but when I access my admin dashboard it says "PHP update recommended" when I opened "learn more about updating PHP" it says

> "Please, be sure that your site is safe! WordPress recommends everyone
> update their PHP versions, but this is often not possible. This is why
> your site is using HardenedPHP, by CloudLinux. HardenedPHP is a way of
> supporting older versions of PHP without compromising security. If
> you’ve been brought here by WordPress’s PHP update warnings, there is
> nothing you need to do. "

how the heck? it's a local server why my admin dashboard keeps popping up a notification to update the PHP.

I tried a lot of solutions:

- clear cash of everything.
- download PHP manually.

is it a redirect-related thing or what?

**Note: I'm fairly new to the programming world**

Comment: How did you update PHP in Wampserver to PHP 7.4? Please check this and confirm you did it in the correct way: http://blog.astemplates.com/change-php-version-wamp/

Comment: yes I have followed the steps above and everything says u run PHP 7.4.27 but in the admin dashboard it recommending to update the PHP

Comment: Also, Go to Windows environment variable window and edit system variable "Path" to add the new PHP path

Comment: didn't work either.

Comment: Apart from the prompt to update PHP on admin dashboard, which is the current version showing in WordPress?

Comment: if u mean WordPress it's 5.9 and PHP 5.6.40

Comment: Did you try to restart the wampserver after the PHP upgrade?

Comment: yes so many times and in every possible way

Comment: i would recommend WSL2 instead of WAMP. it is miles faster and easier to work with (at least if you have some Linux & CLI knowledge)

Comment: Could this be some addon that was added to WP that was supposed to check and encourage you to keep to the latest version of PHP.

Comment: no it was the WordPress itself